# To progress the highlighted view on basis of tableview content height while scrolling in Swift

Tags: swift, uikit, autolayout, tableview, vertical-scrolling

[image]

I'm increasing the width constraint of green view and increasing its width while scrolling the tableView till very bottom. I tried but not getting exact values:

```
  override func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let height = self.tableView?.contentSize.height
    
    if array.count > 0{
        //var hh = CGFloat((tableView?.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.last!.row)!)
        let totalHeight = ((tableView?.contentSize.height)!)
        let totalWidth = (UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
        let ratio = totalWidth / totalHeight
        
        let val = round(CGFloat(globalIndex) / (totalHeight - UIScreen.main.bounds.height) * 100);
        
        viewWidthConstraint.constant = CGFloat(globalIndex) * ratio *  100
    }
  }
```

Comment: Several problems... but first - are all of your rows the same Height? Or are you using dynamic height cells?

Comment: All cells have dynamic height.

Comment: Your calculations are wrong, but never mind that. Since you are using dynamic-height cells, you cannot use `contentSize.height` because that isn't known until you have scrolled all the way to the bottom. So, you need to use the visible cells. But... suppose you have 10 rows. If 4 rows are visible at the start, are you already 40% of the way?